# How to create a mask for jQuery Masked Input Plugin that allow alphanumeric, spaces and accented characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, non-ascii-characters, maskedinput, jquery-mask

How to create a mask for jQuery Masked Input Plugin that allow alphanumeric, spaces and accented characters?

I have

```
$.mask.definitions["A"] = "[a-zA-Z0-9 ]";
$("#input").mask("A?AAAAAAA");
```

But that doesn't include accented characters.

Comment: It doesn't look like that plugin supports unicode.

Answer (score 1):

You can following masking to support alphanumeric and space.

```
jQuery('.alphanumeric-field').mask('Z',{translation:  {'Z': {pattern: /[a-zA-Z0-9 ]/, recursive: true}}});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[data-mask="alfanumeric"]').inputmask({ regex: '^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$' });
$('input[data-mask="alfanumeric1"]').inputmask({ regex: '^[áéíóúàèìòùA-Za-z0-9 ]*$' });
$('input[data-mask="alfanumeric2"]').inputmask({ regex: '^[áéíóúàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙA-Za-z0-9 ]*$' });
$('input[data-mask="alfanumeric3"]').inputmask({ regex: '^[\,\.\:\;áéíóúàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙA-Za-z0-9 ]*$' });

<input data-mask="alfanumeric" type="text" value="">
<input data-mask="alfanumeric1" type="text" value="">
<input data-mask="alfanumeric2" type="text" value="">
<input data-mask="alfanumeric3" type="text" value="">
```

Answer (score -2):

In this way it works perfectly:

```
$('#input').mask('ZZ',{translation:  {'Z': {pattern: /[áéíóúñüàèa-zA-Z0-9\s]/, recursive: true}}});
```

It is important to put the two ZZ to solve a letter jump bug.